# How to obtain daily or weekly edit statistics for a given Wikipedia page

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, wikipedia

I'm wondering if there is a site (or a programatic method) to obtain weekly *edit* statistics for a given wikipedia page.  I know that I can obtain Wikipedia article traffic statistics here: http://stats.grok.se/, but I don't know if Wikipedia logs edit statistics in the same way.

I have found this webpage which generates a graph of the edit history of a webpage by week: https://tools.wmflabs.org/xtools/wikihistory/wh.php?page_title=Bitcoin.  Is there a way to scrape this graph, or find out where the graph is obtaining its statistics?

Comment: If you have coding problem, we will glad to help you. But AFAIK, I see no code...

Answer (score -2):

stats.groke.se uses data dumps found [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/analytics). the wikihistory tool uses info gathered from dumps and Wikimedia servers (which normally you can't have access to) directly. You can also check [this page](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Statistics) for more information and tools regarding Wikimedia and Wikipedia statistics.